# Realm react native schema versioning

Tags: react-native, realm

I have the following 2 schemas in realm.js file

```
    class Bill extends Realm.Object {}
        Bill.schema = {
          name: 'Bill',
          primaryKey: 'id',
          properties: {
            id: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
            year: 'int',
            month: 'int',
            description: 'string',
            dateCreated: 'int',
        }
    };

    class User extends Realm.Object {}
        User.schema = {
          name: 'User',
          primaryKey: 'id',
          properties: {
            id: 'string',
            name: 'string?',
            email: 'string?'
          }
    };

 const realm = new Realm({schema: [Bill, User]}); 

 export default realm;
```

this works perfectly when I first release my app to AppStore or PlayStore. 
I need to change both schema and release to AppStore or PlayStore again and I need to handle both new installation or update of my app where the schema change to following

```
    class Bill extends Realm.Object {}
        Bill.schema = {
          name: 'Bill',
          primaryKey: 'id',
          properties: {
            id: { type: 'string', indexed: true },
            year: 'int',
            month: 'int',
            description: 'string',
            dateCreated: 'int',
            dateDeleted: 'int',
        }
    };

    class User extends Realm.Object {}
        User.schema = {
          name: 'User',
          primaryKey: 'id',
          properties: {
            id: 'string',
            name: 'string?',
            email: 'string?',
            photoUrl: 'string?',
          }
    };
```

by adding one more field in each schema.

So how should I configure my realm schema version?

Should I configure like below:

```
const realm = new Realm([
              {schema: Bill, schemaVersion: 1}, 
              {schema: User, schemaVersion: 1}
            ]);
```

But this may crash for new installation.

Comment: Why would that crash for new installations? The schema version doesn't have to start from 0 at the first installation. The only important thing to keep in mind is to increase the schema version every time you make changes to your schema.

Comment: first installation may crash as the schema doesn't has version 1 and only version 0 ?

Comment: As I've already stated, the schema doesn't need to start from version 0... You can start it from whatever number you like, it can be 9999 as well.

Comment: no it won't work. for fresh installation of iOS or android app, if I put schemaVersion 1, it throws exception. 'Unhandled JS Exception: Error: Object type 'User' not found in schema

Answer (score -1):

You should set global `schemaVersion` for all database, not for each model. And perform migrations to the current version, like it's described in [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#performing-a-migration):

> You define a migration and the associated schema version by updating
>   the schemaVersion and defining an optional migration function. Your
>   migration function provides any logic needed to convert data models
>   from previous schemas to the new schema. When opening a Realm the
>   migration function will be applied to update the Realm to the given
>   schema version only if a migration is needed.
>
> If no migration function is supplied then any new properties an
>   automatically added and old properties are removed from the database
>   when updating to the new schemaVersion. If you need to update old or
>   populate new properties when upgrading your version you can do this in
>   the migration function. For example, suppose we want to migrate the
>   Person model declared earlier. You can populate the name property of
>   the new schema using the old firstName and lastName properties:
>
> ```
> Realm.open({
>   schema: [PersonSchema],
>   schemaVersion: 1,
>   migration: (oldRealm, newRealm) => {
>     // only apply this change if upgrading to schemaVersion 1
>     if (oldRealm.schemaVersion < 1) {
>       const oldObjects = oldRealm.objects('Person');
>       const newObjects = newRealm.objects('Person');
>
>       // loop through all objects and set the name property in the new schema
>       for (let i = 0; i < oldObjects.length; i++) {
>         newObjects[i].name = oldObjects[i].firstName + ' ' + oldObjects[i].lastName;
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }).then(realm => {
>   const fullName = realm.objects('Person')[0].name;
> });
> ```
>
> Once the migration is successfully completed the Realm and all of its
>   objects can be accessed as usual by your app.

Comment: I don’t need migration function as I am only adding fields

Comment: Well, yes you do need migration, because adding fields is still schema modification, and **has to be handled**. But anyways, you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink.